# Show that $\lfloor 2n/p^k\rfloor$ is odd if $p^\alpha$ is in the prime factorization of $\binom{2n}n$

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients, prime-factorization

I am trying to work out the details of the accepted answer here:

[On a property of the binomial coefficient](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/60403/on-a-property-of-the-binomial-coefficient?noredirect=1)

To summarize: We have $p$ a prime divisor of $\binom{2n}n$ and $\alpha$ the exponent in the prime factorization.  That is to say

$$ p^\alpha | \binom{2n}n $$
$$ p^{\alpha+1} \require{cancel}\cancel{|} \binom{2n}n $$

We show that

$$ \alpha = \sum_{k=1}^\infty (\lfloor 2n/p^k \rfloor - 2\lfloor n/p^k\rfloor )$$

We want to show that if $k\le \alpha$ then $\lfloor 2n/p^k \rfloor$ is odd.

I suspect we want to consider the case of an odd prime separately, so for now let's assume $p$ is odd.

---

I'm unsure of exactly how to work with the floor function here.  I can see that, splitting into integer and fractional parts,

\[ n/p^k = \lfloor n/p^k \rfloor + { n/p^k} \Rightarrow \\
2n/p^k = 2\lfloor n/p^k \rfloor + 2{ n/p^k} \Rightarrow\\
\lfloor 2n/p^k \rfloor = 2\lfloor n/p^k\rfloor + x \]

where $x=0,1$ and as far as I can tell we can't get any good insights into $x$ in this setting.

I can see that this implies

$$ \alpha = \sum_{k=1}^\infty x $$

Also clearly when $n < p^k$ we have that $\lfloor n/p^k \rfloor = 0$ so that these terms in the sum could be dropped.  If we call $\beta$ the exponent such that $p^\beta \le n < p^{\beta +1}$ then we have that $\alpha\le \beta$.  But from here I'm stuck and not really all that sure if I've done anything useful.

---

Edit: I actually didn't see the second answer at that link until just now (the accepted one by TMM).  I see that he rearranged the terms at the end.  He then says that

$$ \lfloor 2n/p^k \rfloor - 2\lfloor n/p^k \rfloor = 1$$

if and only if $\lfloor 2n/p^k \rfloor$ is odd (and otherwise is 0).  I haven't yet worked out how that follows from the work he has above, but I can probably get there on my own.  What I really don't get is how this answers the question.  If $k\le \alpha$ then it seems that somehow this is supposed to tell us that $\lfloor 2n/p^k\rfloor - 2\lfloor n/p^k\rfloor = 1$.  At that point we can use what he found to get the desired result.  But I don't see how we get to the point where we can infer that $\lfloor 2n/p^k\rfloor - 2\lfloor n/p^k\rfloor = 1$.

Comment: I must be doing something wrong. If $n = 4$, we get $\binom{8}{4} = 2.5.7$ and $\lfloor 8/2^1\rfloor =  4$.

Comment: @sku Yeah I stated the thing to prove wrongly. I thought it was equivalent to the given statement, so this confusion is why I was misunderstanding the rest of the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not true that $\lfloor 2n/p^k \rfloor$ is odd if $1\le k\le \alpha$.

For example, consider $n=5, p=2$.
$\binom{2n}n=2^2\cdot3^2\cdot7$.
Let $k=2\le\alpha=2$.
However, $\lfloor 2n/p^k \rfloor=\lfloor 10/2^2 \rfloor=2$ is even.

For example, consider $n=18, p=3$.
$\binom{2n}n=2^2×3×5^2×7×11×19×23×29×31$.
Let $k=1\le\alpha=1$.
However, $\lfloor 2n/p^k \rfloor=\lfloor 36/3^1 \rfloor=12$ is even.

---

To show that $ \lfloor 2n/p^k \rfloor - 2\lfloor n/p^k \rfloor = 1$ if and only if $\lfloor 2n/p^k \rfloor$ is odd, let us prove the general fact.

Claim: $ \lfloor 2x \rfloor - 2\lfloor x \rfloor = 1$ if and only if $\lfloor 2x \rfloor$ is odd.

Proof: $x = \lfloor x\rfloor + \{x\}$. There are two cases.

- $0\le\{x\}\lt\frac12$. Then  $\lfloor 2x\rfloor=2\lfloor x\rfloor$ is even .
- $\frac12\le\{x\}\lt1$. Then  $\lfloor 2x\rfloor=2\lfloor x\rfloor+1$ is odd.

Comment: I'm confused, isn't $\lfloor 10/2 \rfloor = 5$?

Comment: I see--I think I was somewhat misunderstanding the problem as it was stated in my textbook.  I was a little worried that this is what was happening.